# Where are the spoons?

Tags: plot-explanation, bone-tomahawk

In *Bone Tomahawk,* when Sheriff Franklin's wife recovers from her convalescence after her bout with pneumonia and cooks breakfast, she complains that she can not find what the sheriff has done with the spoons while she was sick in bed. He says they are not in any logical place.

Then they are interrupted.

Where are the spoons? Why aren't they anywhere sensible? Why doesn't Sheriff Franklin pass their location to his wife via Deputy Chicory?

Answer (score 5):

**This is just an anecdotal scene of married life.** If you recall, the Sheriff forgot about the spoons too when he served Backup Deputy Chicory that <s>tea</s> corn soup. And when his wife can't find them either, he's puzzled just like her. *They have simply misplaced the spoons*, like people often  misplace things and find them later. It could always be a metaphor for something, but *it has no bearing on the plot*.